# Dynamically change the Visibility of a Grid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8, visibility

I have a `Grid` with `TextBlock` in it:

```
<Grid x:Name="GridLayout" Margin="4,0,4,1" Grid.Row="2" Background="#accdd7">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Name="Title" 
               Grid.Row="0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               Padding="10,2,10,2"
               Style="{StaticResource PromptTextStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

I am setting this `TextBlock` value programatically:

```
Title.Text = myObject.Title;
```

Now here `myObject.Title` may be Null or Empty sometimes at that time I need to hide this entire `Grid`.

How to acheive this?

Answer (score 4):

Set `x:Name` on `TextBlock`. Then apply `dataTriggers` on Grid's style to collapsed the visibility when `Text` is set to null or empty string on TextBlock.

```
    <Grid xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
          x:Name="GridLayout" Margin="4,0,4,1" Grid.Row="2" Background="#accdd7">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Title" 
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   Padding="10,2,10,2"
                   Style="{StaticResource PromptTextStyle}"/>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=Title}"
                                 Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=Title}" 
                                 Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: You mean ii just need to add this in my xml file ?

Comment: Give `x:Name` to your textBlock like i did in sample above. Also make sure to add `sys` namespace and apply Style under Grid tag.

Comment: sorry i didnt get what you are saying can you please shoiw me how to do with my code ?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Replace your xaml with the one posted above.

Comment: It says that Triggers is not recognised or accisable, i am working on Windows phone 8 app

Comment: You need to use [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) for windows phone 8.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49048/discussion-between-user3114009-and-rohit-vats)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, in code behind

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(myObject.Title))
{
GridLayout.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
Title.Text=string.Empty;
}
else
{
Title.Text = myObject.Title;
GridLayout.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: thanks i did it, i need your help please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191160/avoid-nullpointer-exception-when-parsing-xml

Answer (score 0):

May the answer above is for Windows Phone 7

I solved it myself.

Here is how i did.

In the Xaml make the Visibility of the grid item to be collapsed by default, and now in code check the myObject.Title is null or not. if not null then set grid visibilty to visible.

Comment: i need help in xml parsing can you help me ?