# In WPF, how to make a hidden grid visible, based on a combobox selection?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

When I select a combobox item, I want the matching grid - which is hidden by default - to become visible. However, the code I have does not seem to work.

```
private void rating_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.rating.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        /*     this.cha1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
             this.cha1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
             this.cha2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
             */
        MessageBox.Show("등급선택을 해주십시오", "알림");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        string a = rating.SelectedValue.ToString();

        if (a == "1차")
        {
            cha1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            cha1.UpdateLayout();

        }
        if (a == "2차")
        {
            cha2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            cha2.UpdateLayout();
        }
        if (a == "연속")
        {
            cha1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            cha1.UpdateLayout();
        }

    }
}
```

XAML

```
<ComboBox 
    Name="rating" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="120" 
    Margin="268,4,0,0" 
    SelectionChanged="rating_SelectionChanged_1"
    >
    <ComboBoxItem Content="1차" Tag="Value1"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="2차" Tag="Value2"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="연속" Tag="Value3"/>
```

More XAML

```
<Grid 
    Name="cha1" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="500" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="390" 
    Margin="0,30,0,0" 
    Visibility="Collapsed"
    >
</Grid>
```

Comment: Or... even: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195871/dynamically-change-the-visibility-of-a-grid-in-wpf

Comment: [This answer requires some modification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22195984/424129) to fit your case: For the DataTriggers, you'll want `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Tag, ElementName=rating}}" Value="Value1" />` etc. Any questions, please ask.